# How can I find an object inside an object by filtering one of its properties?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var myFood = {
    watermelon: {
        color: "Green",
        shape: "Oval"
    },
    apple: {
        color: "Red",
        shape: "Round"
    }
}
```

How can I return which object is round-shaped?

Comment: Use `Object.entries()` and `filter()`.

Comment: So there's no way to return it without passing it as an array?

Comment: Do you need to handle cases where there are multiple "Round" entries?

Comment: You can use `find()` if you just want to find the first match.

Comment: Do you want to find multiple objects or just the first. Edit the question and add the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myFood = {
    watermelon: {
        color: "Green",
        shape: "Oval"
    },
    apple: {
        color: "Red",
        shape: "Round"
    }
}
const checkRoundShape = (foods)=> {
  for(let food in foods){
    if(myFood[food].shape === 'Round') return food
  }
}


console.log(checkRoundShape(myFood))
```

If there are multiple foods with shape Round

```js
var myFood = {
    watermelon: {
        color: "Green",
        shape: "Oval"
    },
    apple: {
        color: "Red",
        shape: "Round"
    },
    orange: {
        color: "orange",
        shape: "Round"
    }
}

const roundShapes = (foods)=> {
  const res = []
  for(let food in foods){
    if(myFood[food].shape === 'Round') res.push(food)
  }
  return res
}

console.log(roundShapes(myFood))
```

Another way to return multiple foods with round shape

```js
var myFood = {
    watermelon: {
        color: "Green",
        shape: "Oval"
    },
    apple: {
        color: "Red",
        shape: "Round"
    },
    orange: {
        color: "orange",
        shape: "Round"
    }
}


const res = Object.entries(myFood).filter(food => food[1].shape === 'Round').map(food => food[0])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.values()` to get an array of the nested objects, then use the `find` method to return the appropriate value.

```
var round = Object.values(myFood).find(({shape}) => shape == "Round");
```

If you need to return the key, use `Object.entries`

```js
var myFood = {
    watermelon: {
        color: "Green",
        shape: "Oval"
    },
    apple: {
        color: "Red",
        shape: "Round"
    }
}
var round = Object.entries(myFood).find(([key, {shape}]) => shape == "Round");
console.log(round && round[0]);
```

Comment: That's the round-shaped object, isn't it? I added a second solution that returns `apple`

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off the answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714811/2504964  If you want all of the "Round" objects

```js
var myFood = {
    watermelon: {
        color: "Green",
        shape: "Oval"
    },
    apple: {
        color: "Red",
        shape: "Round"
    },
    orange: {
        color: "Orange",
        shape: "Round"
    }
}

var foodNames = Object.keys(myFood).filter((key) => myFood[key].shape == "Round");
foodNames.forEach((name) => console.log(myFood[name]));
```